# grouping with window functions? postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, window

i have a short question

```
select 
*
 from 
(
select 1 do_switch, 'abc', '2001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'xyz', '2001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 1 do_switch, 'xyz', '2001-02-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-01-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-02-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-03-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-04-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-05-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-06-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-07-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 1 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-08-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-09-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-10-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 0 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-11-01'::TIMESTAMP 
union all
select 1 do_switch, 'bcd', '2001-12-01'::TIMESTAMP 
) data_set
```

it should give me at the end a resultset where i have an additional column 
which is a unique number per "group"
the group start from 1/0 and goes till the last 0 entry for the same name

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifGg3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifGg3.png)

can I achieve this with a window function
?
i tried with different dense_rank and row_number with preceeing etc but nothing worked
thanks

Comment: Could you explain on what basis the group number should change? I don't seem to get how you actually decide to change the group

Comment: so the switch should happen after the row where do_switch =1 and stay thill the next row do_swtich=1

Comment: If that's the case why group became 2 in the second row and not 3rd?

Comment: Hi

The first row has no prior row - so it is group 1 .


Than from the 2 row to the next row with a1 should be the next group

Do you understand ?

upto the row with 1 should be always a group

Thank you
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what ordering is happening between "start" and "last", but that's okay for `row_number()`. If needed, you can add that to the first line of the following solution.

```sql
with t1 as (select *, row_number() over (/*define order here*/) from data_set),
     t2 as (select row_number from t1 where do_switch = 1),
     t3 as (select row_number,
                   (
                     select min(t2.row_number)
                       from t2
                      where t2.row_number >= t1.row_number
                   )
              from t1
           )
 select t1.*, dense_rank() over (order by min) from t1 join t3 using (row_number);
```

```
 do_switch |   name   |      timestamp      | row_number | dense_rank 
-----------+----------+---------------------+------------+------------
         1 | abc      | 2001-01-01 00:00:00 |          1 |          1
         0 | xyz      | 2001-01-01 00:00:00 |          2 |          2
         1 | xyz      | 2001-02-01 00:00:00 |          3 |          2
         0 | bcd      | 2001-01-01 00:00:00 |          4 |          3
         0 | bcd      | 2001-02-01 00:00:00 |          5 |          3
         0 | bcd      | 2001-03-01 00:00:00 |          6 |          3
         0 | bcd      | 2001-04-01 00:00:00 |          7 |          3
         0 | bcd      | 2001-05-01 00:00:00 |          8 |          3
         0 | bcd      | 2001-06-01 00:00:00 |          9 |          3
         0 | bcd      | 2001-07-01 00:00:00 |         10 |          3
         1 | bcd      | 2001-08-01 00:00:00 |         11 |          3
         0 | bcd      | 2001-09-01 00:00:00 |         12 |          4
         0 | bcd      | 2001-10-01 00:00:00 |         13 |          4
         0 | bcd      | 2001-11-01 00:00:00 |         14 |          4
         1 | bcd      | 2001-12-01 00:00:00 |         15 |          4
(15 rows)
```

If there's a primary key in `data_set`, you can return it from `t3` to use in the final join instead. That is,

```
with ...
     t2 as (select row_number ...),
     t3 as (select id, ...)
select data_set.*, dense_rank() ... join t3 using (id)
```

Comment: thanks it is working but not really fast but thanks anyway